# Label on lateral bar of density plot

Tags: plotting, labeling

I would like to add the label "Omega" on top of the lateral bar in my density plot, like this (I did it using paint):

[image: Example of density plot]

I spent hours on the documentation, but I didn't find how to obtain such a trivial thing...

Comment: Use the option `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "Omega"]`?

Comment: `DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}
 , ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 3}}
    , LegendLabel -> Style["Omega", Bold, 12]]
   , {1.05, 0.5}
   ]
 ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Explicitly specify the [`PlotLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegend.html) as a [`BarLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html) then you can use the option [`LegendLabel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendLabel.html)

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y],
 {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3},
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "Omega"]]
```

[image]